# AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'runserver' in django

Tags: python, django

I have a functional test 'y1.py' which I am trying to call from within a python/django function. Inside the calling function I have:

```
import unittest
import ft1.y1
unittest.main(module=ft1.y1.py)
```

y1.py:

```
   from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re    

class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_y1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Weather").click()
        driver.save_screenshot('out11.png')    

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()


Exception Type: AttributeError at /runtest/
Exception Value: 'module' object has no attribute 'runserver'
```

How can I fix this?

edit:

I tried:

```
unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=[])
```

and got:

```
Traceback:
File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  114.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "F:\envs\r1\driver1\driver\views.py" in runtest
  31.     unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=[])
File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\unittest\main.py" in __init__
  93.         self.progName = os.path.basename(argv[0])    

Exception Type: IndexError at /runtest/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

edit 2:

I'm confused it says test OK , but there is an error:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.    

Validating models...    

0 errors found
January 31, 2014 - 14:42:50
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'driver1.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 6.286s    

OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\dj_static.py", line 59, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 206, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "F:\envs\r1\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 114, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\envs\r1\driver1\driver\views.py", line 32, in runtest
    unittest.main(module=ft1.y1, argv=sys.argv[:1])
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "f:\ppython275\App\Lib\unittest\main.py", line 234, in runTests
    sys.exit(not self.result.wasSuccessful())
SystemExit: False
[31/Jan/2014 14:43:03] "GET /runtest/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to run unitest and selenium from a view?  You should consider launching a [second process for that](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).  This gives you better separation between your django modules and tested modules. If you insist on using unittest.main(), pass the argv and exit params.

```
import sys
unittest.main(module=ft.gtest, argv=sys.argv[:1], exit=False)
```

See also:

- [TextTestRunner](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner)
- [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/)
- [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)

(Edited)

Comment: edited: added exit arg, but you should really use a different process.