# How to to run unitest and selenium from a django view?

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have a functional test 'y1.py' which I have exported from the selenium IDE. It looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re    

class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_y1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Weather").click()
        driver.save_screenshot('out11.png')    

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I am trying to call this directly from within a python/django function. while investigating this I came across: [AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute 'runserver' in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21414665/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-runserver-in-django), where Udi states:

> Are you trying to run unitest and selenium from a view? You should
>   consider launching a second process for that.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start django server as new process with [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).